# Python csv - replace any columns with specified value

Tags: python, csv

I have the following input file with a header row:
test_in.csv

```
LON,LAT,NUMBER,STREET,UNIT,CITY,DISTRICT,REGION,POSTCODE,ID,HASH
-72.5708234,41.4155142,39,HICKORY LA,,,,,,,8a0df668e0d49b02
-72.5647745,41.4160301,1213,KILLINGWORTH RD,,,,,,,b3ecaab86e476f46
```

I need to replace any of the columns with a specified string
for example CITY column's data should be replaced from "" to "MyCity"
My code only outputs the header and first row

python test_forcefld.py test_in.csv MyCity CITY out_test.csv

```
import csv
import sys

in_file_name = sys.argv[1]
force_data = sys.argv[2]
force_fld = sys.argv[3]
out_file_name = sys.argv[4]

# First read top row/header from input file
fieldnames = []
for filename in [in_file_name]:
  with open(filename, "rb") as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    headers = next(reader)
    for h in headers:
        fieldnames.append(h)
#print headers to output file
with open(out_file_name, 'w') as fou:
    dw = csv.DictWriter(fou, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    dw.writeheader()

f_in2 = open(in_file_name, "rb")
reader2 = csv.DictReader(f_in2)  # Uses the field names in this file
datarow = next(reader2)
datarow[force_fld] = force_data
with open(out_file_name, 'wa') as fou:
    dw2 = csv.DictWriter(fou, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    dw2.writeheader()
    dw2.writerow(data row)
```

Output shows

```
LON,LAT,NUMBER,STREET,UNIT,CITY,DISTRICT,REGION,POSTCODE,ID,HASH
-72.5708234,41.4155142,39,HICKORY LA,,MyCity,,,,,8a0df668e0d49b02
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little difficult to read, but assuming **datarow** is a dictionary containing your records:

In your last row, change

```
dw2.writerow(datarow)
```

Into

```
dw2.writerows(datarow)
```

While you're at it, you should also consider using datarow.keys() for your fieldnames, for conciseness.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, you just need `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(in_file_name, sep=',')
df['CITY'].fillna('MyCity', inplace=True)
```

And to save it:

```
df.to_csv(out_file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try somthing like this in order to have your desired file:

I'm assuming your input file is called `f_input.txt` and your output file is called `f_output.txt`:

```
data = list(k.rstrip().split(',') for k in open("f_input.txt", 'r'))

with open("f_output.txt", 'a+') as f:
    f.write(",".join(data[0]) + '\n')
    for k in data[1:]:
        # Modify the positions of k[:n] + your data + k[n+1]
        # if you need to handle another position
        f.write(",".join(k[:6]) + "MyCity" + ",".join(k[7:]) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the end:

```
import csv
import sys

in_file_name = sys.argv[1]
force_data = sys.argv[2]
force_fld = sys.argv[3]
out_file_name = sys.argv[4]

# First read top row/header from input file
fieldnames = []
for filename in [in_file_name]:
  with open(filename, "rb") as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    headers = next(reader)
    for h in headers:
        fieldnames.append(h)

f_in2 = open(in_file_name, "r")
#print headers to output file
fou = open(out_file_name, 'wa')
dw = csv.DictWriter(fou, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
dw.writeheader()
reader2 = csv.DictReader(f_in2)  # Uses the field names in this file
for row in reader2:
    row[force_fld] = force_data
    dw2 = csv.DictWriter(fou, delimiter=',', fieldnames=fieldnames)
    dw2.writerow(row)
```